# Как в кастомной директиве сделать динамический ng-model в шаблоне

Tags: angularjs

```
app.directive('formInput', function(translations){
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template: '<input class="form-control" ng-model=vm.user**[formGroup.attribute]**></input>',
        require: [
          '^formFor',
          '^formGroup'
        ],
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrls) {
          var formForCtrl = $ctrls[0];
          var formGroupCtrl = $ctrls[1];
          $attrs.$set('id', formGroupCtrl.inputId(formForCtrl.name));
          $attrs.$set('placeholder', translations.User[formGroupCtrl.attribute]);
        }
      }
});
```

а именно в строке `ng-model=vm.user.` + `formGroup.attribute`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для использования значения в шаблоне, его надо добавить либо в скоп, либов контроллер, например так:

```
app.directive('formInput', function(translations){
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template: '<input class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user[formGroupAttribute]"></input>',
        require: [
          '^formFor',
          '^formGroup'
        ],
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrls) {
          var formForCtrl = $ctrls[0];
          var formGroupCtrl = $ctrls[1];
          $scope.formGroupAttribute = formGroupCtrl.attribute;
          $attrs.$set('id', formGroupCtrl.inputId(formForCtrl.name));
          $attrs.$set('placeholder', translations.User[formGroupCtrl.attribute]);
        }
      }
});
```